# Server technology that allows client to define it's JSON response format

Tags: json, mobile

So last year, someone introduced me to an off-the-shelf database server package/ technology that would take a request from a client and would serve up the information in a JSON format that was defined in the request. Having previously had to develop mobile client applications using apis designed for websites, this seemed like a wondrous thing. Being able to make one call and receive only the data you asked for and in the format that suited your code would be a godsend.

Unfortunately, I didn't get the opportunity to work directly with the technology and I have subsequently forgotten what it was called. Neither Google nor StackOverflow has been my friend. It's difficult to formulate the search terms to get the right hit I suppose. Nobody I currently work with has heard of this and I have lost contact with the people who originally introduced me to it.

It's driving me nuts. Does anyone know the name of this package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technology I was thinking of was [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/).